# Why doesn't GetMenu work on Mozilla menus?

Tags: delphi, mozilla, menu

I want to get the Mozilla menu handle but [`GetMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647640.aspx) returns zero. On Notepad it is true. Why?

Answer (score 7):

Because Mozilla uses its own engine to display the menu, while Notepad uses the menu system provided by the Windows API.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to read the menus then of course you can always use the accessibility APIs.